# Bootstrap v 3.2 Border across multiple columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to stick to the Bootstrap design paradigm of `container > row > column`, but I'm admittedly new to this and curious about something.

If I'm only putting content in the columns, as I believe I'm supposed to do, then Bootstrap's CSS puts a 15px gutter at the left and right edges of the page (I know it also puts them between disparate columns.) For design aesthetics I'd like to put a border above my content, and I'd like to do so **without** having it run into the gutter space.

[Plunk included](http://plnkr.co/edit/9lCs7UuvR8KoLRRvX17m?p=preview). As you can see, When I try to style the same element containing the content, it results in the `border-top` attribute (blue and green colored in my example) running into both gutters. When I create a new element above the content and attribute it with `margin-left, margin-right` values, that seems to work for the left edge of the border but not for the right one (orange color in my example). I just want the border to line up with my text.

What is the best way to accomplish this? I could change the margins or padding for the element itself but then I feel like I'm messing with Bootstrap's plumbing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this [**plunk**](http://plnkr.co/edit/sp6Z71qxcA69geBCf4kF?p=preview). I've wrapped the content inside `<div class="col-xs-8 opportunity-results">` with a `<p>` tag and then applied a `border-top` to that `<p>` tag. Moreover, I've assigned the property of `display: block` to the `<a>` tag inside `<div class="col-xs-4 new-search clear-all">` and then applied a `border-top` to that `<a>` tag.

If you want to have the border-top only above the text then please check this **[plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/gccfmizORBe1hOupaItk?p=preview)**.

**UPDATE:**

To make both the blue and the green border-top to touch, you can use the `:after` psuedo selector on `.opportunity-results` like this:

```
.opportunity-results:after {
     position: absolute;
     content: '';
     border-top: 1px solid blue;
     width: 100%;
     height: 2px;
     left: 15px;
     top: 0px;
}
```

Here's the **[plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/ErIUlOK3HRxjT2QyDhJA?p=preview)** for it.

Comment: Thank you. Both your plunks accomplish keeping the border out of the gutters at the edge. Is there anyway to do this while getting the blue and green lines to touch as well?